# for..in.. or for..in range(..)?

Tags: python, list, iterator

I'e heard iterator in my cs class but I didn't really get it. Is it somewhat related to this problem? Basically I'm trying to figure out when should we say

```
for i in L
    ...i
```

and when we say

```
for i in range(L)
    ...i
```

I used the first expression in Java and it always work, e.g. a set of array list. But in Python the first way is not always working? I'm at the very beginning of learning programming so please provide some resources to learn about this if possible. If there's duplicate please send me a link I'll look at it and delete this one. Thank you !

Comment: If you add semicolon it should work. What was the exact problem?

Comment: the edit that I have done will work so you dont explicitly need an iterator. this is the way to foreach in python...

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan And that's why you shouldn't do such edits. If the problem is just a typo, you shouldn't fix it with edits.

Comment: Guys I just realized the original one is not the one I want to ask. So I changed it.

Answer (score 4):

Colon is missing

```
for i in [1,2,3,4]:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
for e in L:
...e
```

When you can work directly on the elements and you don't need to know the indices. I personnaly use "e" instead of "i" in that case because it reminds me of "element". Example :

```
for e in "abc":
    print(e)
```

> a
>
> b
>
> c

And use the

```
for i in range(L):
...i
```

when you need to have the indices. Example :

```
L = [0, 3, 2, 4]
for i in range(len(L)-1):
    print(L[i] > L[i+1])
```